# Cyclic permutation operators in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

I need a python functional (a function that creates functions), which creates all cyclic permutation operators for a list of length N.

For a python list a (e.g. `a = [1, 2, 3, 4,5,6], N= 6`), one can define a function

```
def cyclic_perm(a):
    n = len(a)
    b = [[a[i - j] for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]
    return b
```

that gives you all the possible, cyclic permutations of a list, in this case 6 lists.

I would like the function to give me not the list, but (in this case) 6 operators, that ,when applied to the list, each give one of the permuted lists.

Comment: I'm not sure what the last sentence means. Could you provide an example?

Comment: Please update your question with an example of usage that assumes you already have your function which creates functions.

Comment: Also you may want to just store the options in a dictionary. But please provide a desired output.

Comment: On a side note, you are probably better off using `itertools.permutations` than reinventing the wheel

Comment: You already have it there `lambda a, j: [a[i - j] for i in range(len(a))]`. This is a function that given a list and a shift returns a rotated list.

Comment: @DeepSpace Rotations are not permutations. They are a subset that maintains the cyclical adjacent.

Comment: @DanD. fair enough, but I'm sure there is an itertools recipe that will not make us (or the OP) reinvent the wheel :) (not that it is that complex in this case...)

Comment: The [usual definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_permutation) of "cyclic permutation" is a completely different concept from what you're asking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not too sure what the goal of this exercise is, but you can do this with partial functions.

```
from functools import partial

def reorder_from_idx(idx, a):
    return a[idx:] + a[:idx]

def cyclic_perm(a):
    return [partial(reorder_from_idx, i) for i in range(len(a))]


a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
result = cyclic_perm(a)
print(result)
#[functools.partial(<function reorder_from_idx at 0x00000298D92189D8>, 0),
# functools.partial(<function reorder_from_idx at 0x00000298D92189D8>, 1),
# functools.partial(<function reorder_from_idx at 0x00000298D92189D8>, 2),
# functools.partial(<function reorder_from_idx at 0x00000298D92189D8>, 3),
# functools.partial(<function reorder_from_idx at 0x00000298D92189D8>, 4),
# functools.partial(<function reorder_from_idx at 0x00000298D92189D8>, 5)]
result[3](a)
#[4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Nice example of partial functions @ParitoshSingh +1 Guess I need to read more about them !

Answer (score 4):

You can write a function which returns functions:

```
def cyclic_perm(a):
    n = len(a)
    b = [[a[i - j] for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]
    return b

def cyclic_perm_func(a):
    n = len(a)
    def wrapper(a, n, j):
        def cyc():
            return [a[i - j] for i in range(n)]
        return cyc
    b = [wrapper(a, n, j) for j in range(n)]
    return b

a = [1, 2, 3, 4,5,6]
print(cyclic_perm(a))  # Your original function
f = cyclic_perm_func(a) # f is now a list of functions
print([g() for g in f])  # Let's call each in turn
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1]]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1]]
```

Note the `wrapper()` which is the way of capturing all the parameters which the wrapped function `cyc()` needs in each instance.

Comment: Maybe a bit late but  this is so extremely brilliant! Just needed to say this; really impressive!  Thanks; this was just what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following. Calling `cyclic_perm` function on a input_list will return list of operators (functions) that when called on the input_list will give you the desired result.

```
input_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]


def cyclic_perm(a):
    n = len(a)
    result = []
    for j in range(n):
        def f(l, k=j):
            return list(map(lambda i: l[i - k], range(n)))
        result.append(f)
    return result


for op in cyclic_perm(input_list):
    print(op(input_list))
```

Answer (score 1):

I interpret your request as *"given a number of cycles `n`, implement a function that accepts `n` and returns a function that when passed an iterable, returns the iterable shifted `n` positions."*

Consider [`more_itertools.circular_shifts`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.circular_shifts):

**Given**

```
import functools as ft

import more_itertools as mit


iterable = range(6, 10)
```

**Code**

```
def composed_shifts(n):
    """Return a function of `n` circular shifts."""
    def f(x):    
        return ft.partial(mit.circular_shifts(x).__getitem__, n)()
    return f
```

**Demo**

```
composed_shifts(1)                                         # 1
# <function __main__.composed_shifts.<locals>.f(x)>

composed_shifts(1)(iterable)                               # 2
# (7, 8, 9, 6)

composed_shifts(3)(iterable)
# (9, 6, 7, 8)
```

---

**Details**

Our `composed_shifts()` function accepts an integer of `n` shifts and

1. returns a function
2. that when passed an iterable, returns the value at the index of the list from `mit.circular_shifts()`.  See more details below.

A [circular shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_shift) is a specific type of cyclic permutation, demonstrated below:

```
mit.circular_shifts(iterable))
```

Output

```
[(6, 7, 8, 9),                                             # 0 shifts
 (7, 8, 9, 6),                                             # 1   " 
 (8, 9, 6, 7),                                             # 2   " 
 (9, 6, 7, 8)]                                             # 3   "
```

As shown, a list of all circular shifts is returned.  All we need is an index to select a specific shift, `n`.  This selection is accomplished by `__getitem__`, which is partialed to delay indexing the future list.

Summary

- The shift (index) `n` is partialed into `__getitem__()` of `mit.circular_shifts()`
- The inner function `f` [composes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36273977/are-currying-and-composition-the-same-concept-in-javascript) the latter partial function

Install this third-party library via `> pip install more_itertools`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is too slow, but why not just use mod?  E.g.

```
def cycle(colors,n):
   return [colors[(n + i) % len(colors)] for i in range(len(colors))]
```

Then you could get your list of permutations with:

```
[cycle(colors,j) for j in range(len(colors))]
```