# What's the clean way to cascade functions in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

Firstly, this is not about chaining. I understand chaining is around function methods and this isn't, and I haven't been able to find a term for this.

Basically what I'm looking for is a clean way to pass output of one function into another and chain it. Something that looks like this

```
const updatedAssets = addCategory(addTagLine(addTags(addImages(addPoints(addID(addTitle(assets)))))));
```

Basically `assets` is an object and each function will add new keys and values into it.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28821765/function-composition-in-javascript ?

Comment: Not sure what do you want to ask. Your code as is would work completely fine, and it is very easy to do in JavaScript. Do you mean how to do it in TypeScript?

Comment: Sounds like you found the solution already. Why are you not satisfied with the code that you posted?

Comment: _"Firstly, this is not about chaining."_, _"Basically what I'm looking for is a clean way to pass output of one function into another and chain it."_, _"Something that looks like this"_ Is the requirement the "look" of the pattern or the actual handling of input and output?

Comment: @t.niese Why do you think it's not clear? Sure, there's a lot of things happening in a single line, but it's quite clear *what* is happening.

Comment: Yes it looks and works fine, but is this a scalable solution you use generally? What if there were like 20 different functions and i had to iterate through each and pass the result into the next one to find the output

Comment: JS doesn't have something like a pipe operator (yet), and I guess you don't want to compose those functions. Maybe you can put them in a box like `[assets].map(addTitle).map(addID).map(addPoints)`

Comment: What is the difference between 20 function calls and 7 function calls if those function calls are necessary to return the expected result using the pattern that you have chosen to use?

Comment: @Bergi that one-liner might look ok at first. But if you need to change the ordering of the functions, if you need to remove functions or add some more, then this construct becomes really annoying. While the reordering might work in the code it would still be horrible for code audit to see what has changed, as the whole construct would always change completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to avoid the nesting and improve readability, you can make an array of your functions and use `reduce()`/`reduceRight()` to compose them. For example:

```js
let one = n => "one " + n
let two = n => "two " + n
let three = n => "three " + n

let functions = [one, two, three]

let res = functions.reduce((res, f) => f(res), "go")
console.log(res)

// or the opposite direction:
let resRev = functions.reduceRight((res, f) => f(res), "go")
console.log(resRev)
```